# Bash inline version of piping file to bluetoothctl

Tags: linux, bash, inline

**bt.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e 'scan on\n'
sleep 2
echo -e 'devices\n'
echo -e 'quit\n'
```

If I pipe the above file to bluetoothctl, it works as expected.

```
# ./bt.sh  | bluetoothctl
```

But how can I do that as an inline script, I have tried the following but it does not work and bluetoothctl does not appear to register the commands:

```
echo -e 'scan on' | bluetoothctl && sleep 2 && echo -e 'devices\n' | bluetoothctl && echo -e 'quit\n' | bluetoothctl;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a command list:

```
{   printf 'scan on\n\n'
    sleep 2
    printf 'devices\n\n'
    printf 'quit\n\n'
} | bluetoothctl
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete example of how to interact with bluetoothctl and get its output.
A named pipe is used to feed bluetoothctl. 
You can modify the function *bleutoothctl_writer* to read commands from a file

```
#!/bin/bash
pipe=/tmp/btctlpipe 
output_file=/tmp/btctl_output

if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
  mkfifo $pipe
fi

trap terminate INT
function terminate()
{
  killall bluetoothctl &>/dev/null
  rm -f $pipe
}

function bleutoothctl_reader() 
{
  {
    while true
    do
      if read line <$pipe; then
          if [[ "$line" == 'exit' ]]; then
              break
          fi          
          echo $line
      fi
    done
  } | bluetoothctl > "$output_file"
}


function bleutoothctl_writer() 
{
  cmd=$1
  printf "$cmd\n\n" > $pipe
}

bleutoothctl_reader &
sleep 1
bleutoothctl_writer "scan on"
sleep 15
bleutoothctl_writer "scan off"
sleep 1
bleutoothctl_writer "devices"
sleep 1
bleutoothctl_writer "exit"

device_list=$(cat $output_file | grep -e '^Device.*' | sed 's/Device //g')

echo "$device_list"
terminate
```